# Waiting for another application window

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

What is the best way (with a view to optimization and using system resources) to make waiting in my application when window of another app will be shown?

For example:

1. My application starts.
2. **Waiting while, for example,
   *Notepad* will be started so i can get handle of its window.**
3. Using handle im doing something with
   it and then closing my app.

How to accomplish item 2? I know only one possible way: just check if handle exists in loop using `FindWindow`. But I hope there is a more smart solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launched the process (with `CreateProcess`) use `WaitForInputIdle` and then start the `FindWindow` loop. Adding a `Sleep(20)` or something to the loop will ensure your resource usage is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think the same... I think the best way is windows hooking process... [USING HOOKS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_events)

... Please see: [WH_CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_cbthook) and you have to be watching the event: [HCBT_CREATEWND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)